# Does a method exist to check if a variable is Nothing or WhiteSpace?

Tags: string, julia, isnullorempty

C# has [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0), do we have a `IsNothingOrWhiteSpace(String)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? A string cannot be nothing or null. It can be empty or contain only whitespace characters. Check for that, don't mess around with `Nothing` and other unrelated concepts.

Comment: @DNF - I was asking in reference to the C# version, which does check for `Null`.

Comment: Yes, but why do this in Julia?

Comment: @DNF - I saw the C# version and wondered why an equivalent method didn't exist. I decided to ask and then researched how to write it.

Comment: There is no such function in Base Julia. A string in Julia cannot be null or nothing, but it can be empty or contain only whitespace. The answers should explain this instead of trying come up with a Julia translation. That's not the fault of the OP, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A slightly more elegant way than the other answer would be to fully use the multiple dispatch:

```
isNullOrWS(::Type{Nothing}) = true
isNullOrWS(::Nothing) = true
isNullOrWS(verify::AbstractString) = isempty(strip(verify))
isNullOrWS(::Any) = false
```

This actually results also in a faster assembly code.

```
julia> dat = fill(Nothing, 100);

julia> @btime isNullOrWS.($dat);
  174.409 ns (2 allocations: 112 bytes)

julia> @btime IsNullOrWhiteSpace.($dat);
  488.205 ns (2 allocations: 112 bytes)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to explain why no such function exists in Julia?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel - In `C#`, a method or constructor that requires a `String` will accept `Null`, and if I don't use any specific `String` method, for example, `trim()`, no exception will be raised. In Julia, a `MethodError` will be raised because it can't find a method that will take `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the documentation and it doesn't seem to exist, but you can write it yourself.

```
function IsNullOrWhiteSpace(verify::Any)
  # If verify is nothing, then the left side will return true.
  # If verify is Nothing, then the right side will be true. 
  return isnothing(verify) || isa(nothing,verify)
end 

function IsNullOrWhiteSpace(verify::AbstractString)
  return isempty(strip(verify))
end

println(IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nothing)) # true
println(IsNullOrWhiteSpace(" ")) # true
```

Might not be the best way to do it, but it works.

**Why do we need both `isnothing()` and `isa()`?**

Let's see what will happen when we use `isnothing()` with `nothing` and `Nothing`.

```
println(isnothing(nothing)) # true
println(isnothing(Nothing)) # false
```

**We obviously want to handle `Nothing`, how do we do it?**

Using [`isa()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.isa), it will test if `nothing` is a type of `Nothing`.